# How to convert this usql to valid sql query

Tags: sql, u-sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
d.id AS id, 
CASE
    WHEN (c.a = 'UNK' ? NULL : c.a) IS NOT NULL THEN c.a
    WHEN (b.a = 'UNK' ? NULL : b.a) IS NOT NULL THEN b.a
    WHEN (c.e = 'UNK' ? NULL : c.e) IS NOT NULL THEN c.e
    ELSE b.e
END AS output,
FROM 
   db.table
...random irrelevant joins..
```

I have traced the problem down to the case end part of my code.   I get a parse exception error.  I am assuming `(c.a = 'UNK' ? NULL : c.a)` is not supported.  How would I convert this?

Comment: can you provide sample output??

Comment: Your original U-SQL could be better written either with a `CASE` expression or with the ternary C# expression instead of mixing the two too:

    SELECT DISTINCT d.id AS id,
           c.a != "UNK" ? c.a : 
           b.a != "UNK" ? b.a :
           c.e != "UNK" ? c.e : b.e AS output
    FROM db.table;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the logic correctly, a simple comparison will do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.id AS id, 
       (CASE WHEN c.a <> 'UNK' THEN c.a
             WHEN b.a <> 'UNK' THEN b.a
             WHEN c.e <> 'UNK' THEN c.e
             ELSE b.e
        END) AS output,
FROM . . .
```

`NULL` fails the `<>` comparison, so this should be semantically equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

It is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
d.id AS id, 
CASE
    WHEN c.a != 'UNK' THEN c.a
    WHEN b.a != 'UNK' THEN b.a
    WHEN c.e != 'UNK' THEN c.e
    ELSE b.e
END AS output,
FROM db.table;
```

Alternatively `(c.a = 'UNK' ? NULL : c.a) IS NOT NULL` is the same as `NULLIF(c.a, 'UNK') IS NOT NULL` => `c.a != 'UNK'`